# Is consumable in-app purchase is available with different tires?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes

I am bit new for in-App purchase. I want user to buy different digital content with different price.
Like i have list of video but user can only buy a single video which he/she select. (after purchasing any video i will manage from my server side to make that video available to user).
But there can be possibility many video in single tier and i want user buy again same tire for another video. so i think i have to go with consumable type.
But i am not sure consumable IAP is available with tires or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given product identifier, it will have a single tier assignment. Answering your question "literally", the answer is "no".

As you have a server you can work around this. The better solution if you want to control tier pricing is to have your server vend to the client (the app) the appropriate product identifier to use.

The net effect of this would achieve what you want. This does mean slightly more complicated server to managed the proper vending of product identifiers to video. And depending on your approach, you may need some handshaking with the server or maintain some state on the client (all server solution is best here if it can be done).

Actually, this method in general is better, as it also provides the means to be extended into a flexible A/B testing scheme to test pricing.

Comment: I just want user to buy again same tire, for different video (but i will keep same product id), is apple allowed that?

Comment: If it is consumable and your backend can manage it, then yes.